# Include tables name when exporting multiple tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

When exporting multiple tables as csv in PhpMyAdmin, is there a way to include each table name? Similar to the checkbox that allows to include columns header.

I have several similar tables, and table name is an important piece of information for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the Export page, look for the text to "Export tables as separate files" — this gives you a zip file that contains each table as a separate file, including the table name as part of the file name for each.

There's no way to add the table name in to the file itself, but I think most CSV tools wouldn't know what to do with such a row anyway. If that's what you're after, it probably wouldn't take too much work to automate parsing the table name from the file name and adding it in using some scripting language.

[image: Export dialog]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unluckily, my version of phpMyAdmin lacks that option. I will contact the webmaster. I solved the problem writing a dedicated php script.

Comment: You can also add your own installation of phpMyAdmin to your web root and not rely on the version you've been given. Glad you were able to easily solve it.